# PresentViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I am trying to present a ViewController which I know can be done with the following line.

```
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However I have a part which is calling the AppDelegate and that is where I run into trouble.

I can manage to sort it out with:

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bvc animated:YES];
```

but as the code implies, this does a navigation push - **how do I it, so that I can do a vertical push up?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present on `navigation controller` -

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```